# Adding varying numbers of labels and sliders programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

In swift and Xcode I want to be able to make an app where the user can enter what subjects they have, and then proceed to the next page, where they are greeted with a page where they can pick how much they like each subject as a percentage, using labels and sliders.

What I am unsure about is how I can add varying amounts of labels and sliders, depending on how many subjects they add.

e.g. if the user inputs Maths, English, and Science, on the next page, I will need to add **exactly** 3 labels and exactly 3 sliders programmatically.

If anyone could tell me how I would go about solving this problem I would much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first page, where the user 'picks' the subject, add these subjects to an array object. The array object will then have a count.

On the second page, pass through the array of 'subject' object inside of an array. Then add a UITableView to the second page. Make a prototype UITableViewCell that contains a UILabel and a UISlider. Then on the UITableViewDelegate and Datasource, set the numRowsForSection to be the count of the array, and the table will draw that many cells. Then pass the subject data from the array to the cell with cellForRowAtIndexPath and continue from there.

If you are not familiar with UITableView and its delegate/datasources, look those up first!

Comment: Thank you for the extremely quick response :) - I will give this a go

Comment: And what do you mean by pass through the array of 'subject' object inside of an array?

Comment: I would create a Subject class with properties such as 'title' 'percentageLikeFactor' .. etc. Then create an array in the first UIViewController i.e.: `var arrSubjects = [Subject]()` .. then when you create new Subject objects, push them to the arrSubjects to fill out the array. When you push the new view controller to the navigation stack, or present it, be sure to add some 'configuration' function that accepts the array i.e. `func configure(arrSubjects: [Subject]) {... set the arr to a variable in the new page and set it in the table datasource.. then reloadData() on the tableview}`

Comment: I am still quite confused. Is it possible you could attach some code please?

Comment: `Class Subject { var title: String?; var percentLiked: Double?   func init(title: String){self.title = title}` in a Subject.swift file. Then in the first controller you can create subjects. `var subject = Subject("Maths"); arrSubject.append(subject);` .. pass the arr to the second controller in a function like shown above. Then do some research on how UITableViews work, and mark my answer as correct when you are done!